# Analoge of BigQuery STRUCT in PostgreSQL and MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Do MySQL and PostgreSQL have analogue of Google BigQuery's `STRUCT`?

It's kinda neat that you can create a structure anywhere with

```
STRUCT(<value_1> as <field_1>, <value_2> as <field_2>, ...)
```

PostgreSQL has `CREATE TYPE`, but it doesn't seem to be as lightweight.

Is there a more or less direct analogue?

For instance in BigQuery we can create a table as follows:

```sql
create or replace table my_dataset.t as (
  select "John" as name, struct("US" as country, "New York" as city) as location union all
  select "James" as name, struct("US" as country, "Seattle" as city) as location
);
```

Country and city are organized into a structure, which is often convenient. E.g. we can list all locations by running

```sql
select location from my_dataset.t;
```

In PostgreSQL this seems to be doable if we create a type. Do I get it right that it's not as straightforward otherwise?

Comment: PostgreSQL has the `ROW(...)` constructor, and you can give query results an alias, so you can get pretty much the same thing.

Comment: It doesnt seem to be quite the same. Row doesn't have column names, while struct does. So with struct you can make later queries simpler, like: `with people as (select "John" as name, struct("US" as country, "New York" as city) as location)
select location.* from people;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1, 2)) AS tab(a, b);

 a | b 
---+---
 1 | 2
(1 row)
```

The example in your comments is a little bit more complicated, but nothing you couldn't do in PostgreSQL:

```
WITH location AS (
        SELECT 'US' AS country,
               'New York' AS city
     ),
     people AS (
        SELECT 'John' AS name,
               location
        FROM location
     )
SELECT (location).* FROM people;
```

Comment: I could not generalize your example to more than one row. In BQ I could do:`with people as (
  select "John" as name, struct("US" as country, "New York" as city) as location union all
  select "James" as name, struct("US" as country, "Seattle" as city) as location
)
select location.* from people;` Is there a PostreSQL analogue? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: A `VALUES` clause can have more than one row, and with a `SELECT` statement, you can use `UNION ALL` to get more rows.

Comment: I reformulated the question. Sorry, I think it wasn't well formulated before.